# Flutter: The method 'add' was called on null

Tags: android, ios, list, flutter, dart

I have created a list as follows:

```
List Links;
```

I use this function to add links:

```
Widget favoriteButton() {
    final _urlKey = GlobalKey<State>();
    return FutureBuilder<WebViewController>(
        key: _urlKey,
        future: _controller.future,
        builder: (BuildContext context,
            AsyncSnapshot<WebViewController> controller) {
          if (controller.hasData) {
            return FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                final String url = await controller.data.currentUrl();
                Links.add(url.substring(30));

                if (Links.isNotEmpty) {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => DemoApp(),
                    ),
                  );
                }
              },
              child: const Icon(Icons.add),
            );
          }
          return Container();
        });
  }
```

But when i call this function i'am getting an error:

**Error:** Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'add' was called on null.

Comment: you need to init array

Comment: tam anlamadım sorunu. "NoSuchMethodError: The method 'add' was called on null." bu sorun çözüldü mü array'i init edince

Comment: Evet, çözüldü. Fakat liste fonksiyon içinde olduğu için başka bir yerden nasıl listeye ulaşacağımı bilmiyorum.

Comment: şimdi başka sorun mu var abi?

Comment: Bu sorun çözüldü fakat başka bir yerde bu listeyi "Links.last" diye çağırdığım zaman "last was called on null" hatası alıyorum.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize an empty `List` at the beginning.

```
List Links = [];
```